# I am getting card with dollars from firebase instead of data in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image: While I am trying to retrieve the data from the firestore, i am getting these type of dollar signs in my cards while fetching the data]

```
snapshot.data!.docs.forEach((doc) {
          Object? data = doc.data();
          propertyCards.add(
            Card(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(
                    (doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)['property_name'] ??
                        ''),
                subtitle: Text((doc.data()
                        as Map<String, dynamic>)['property_location'] ??
                    ''),
                trailing: Text(
                    '\$${(doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)['property_price'] ?? ''}'),
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
```

I am getting the dollar signs while retrieving the data from the firestore, i dont know why i am unable to get the property_name, location and price which are in my firestire.

Comment: You are getting `$` because everything else is a empty string `''`

Comment: Share us the structure of firestore database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use directly map the doc.data() to get the desired result as follows :

```
return ListView(
            children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
              Map<String, dynamic> movie =
                  document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
              return ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(Icons.movie),
                trailing: Text('\$${movie['property_price'] ?? ''}'),
                title: Text(movie['title']),
                subtitle: Text(movie['genre']),
              );
            }).toList(),
          );
```

Although this is implemented in StreamBuilder this is also valid in regular get calls, I have used `'\$${movie['property_price'] ?? ''}'` to display money in dollars using template literals.

The result I got is as follows

[image: Working Dollar sign]

Reference : [Check data access in the Real Time updates section](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#realtime-changes)